# Linux : Copy 3 files text contents into 1 file

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, copy

im on a linux terminal,

cat file1 : 
a
 b
            c

cat file2 : 
d
            
e 
            
f

cat file3 : 
g
            
h
            
i

file4 doesn't exist I have to copy the content of file1 file2 file3 with a **single commande**  (without pipe) into file4 (create 'file4') to get

cat file4 : 
a;d;g
            
b;e;h
            
c;f;i

Comment: "Without pipe" looks like an arbitrary constraint (although the best answer may not use pipes indeed). Is this a homework or a test? What have you tried? Please see [ask] and note Super User is not a code writing service. Questions that lack research effort may get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `paste` command:

```
paste -d ';' file1 file2 file3 >file4
```